# Variance of $x$ co-ordinate of uniform random point on a circle.

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Let $P$ be a point uniformly randomly chosen on the perimiter unit circle. Let $X$ denote its $x$ co-ordinate.  What is the Var$[X]$?

**My method**

By symetery $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0 $ and so Var$[X]$ = $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$

Using a bit of trig I found the CDF of $X^2$ as $ F_{X^2}(t) = \mathbb{P}[X^2 \leq t] = 1-\frac{2cos^{-1}(\sqrt{t})}{\pi}$.

Using Desmos I then differentiated for the PDF and integrated for the expected value which gives $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \frac{1}{2}$. I confirmed this answer using a bit of python.

**Going forward**

Such a simple answer makes me think there must be a neat little trick to find $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \frac{1}{2 } $?

Can someone find an easier way of doing this? Possibly using the law of total variance conditioning on the $y$ co-ordinate?

What about parametrizing the points in polar? Then we only deal with  Uniform $[0,2\pi] $ variable?

**Edit**

I initially intended on finding the variance of the $x$ co-ordinate of a point selected uniformly on the surface of the unit sphere. Could someone give some pointers for this too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed a nice trick for calculating $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$. Notice that
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2+Y^2] = 1,$$
and since $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[Y^2]$ (by symmetry) we have that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\frac12$. The same method can of course be applied to a unit sphere, where the $X,Y$ and $Z$ coordinates must obey $X^2+Y^2+Z^2=1$ and we would thus have
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2]= \frac{1}{3}.$$
You could even generalize that the variance of the $x$-coordinate of a randomly chosen point on the $(n-1)$-sphere is equal to $\frac1n$.

Comment: you are very clever. thank you !